# Why is pandas str.replace returning NaN?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to remove the comma separator from values in a dataframe in Pandas to enable me to convert the to Integers. I have been using the following method:

```
df_orders['qty'] = df_orders['qty'].str.replace(',','')
```

However this seems to be returning NaN values for some numbers which did not originally contain ',' in their values. I have included a sample of my Input data and current output below:

Input:

```
         date      sku  qty
556603  2020-10-25  A   6
590904  2020-10-21  A   5
595307  2020-10-20  A   31
602678  2020-10-19  A   11
615022  2020-10-18  A   2
641077  2020-10-16  A   1
650203  2020-10-15  A   3
655363  2020-10-14  A   18
667919  2020-10-13  A   5
674990  2020-10-12  A   2
703901  2020-10-09  A   1
715411  2020-10-08  A   1
721557  2020-10-07  A   31
740515  2020-10-06  A   49
752670  2020-10-05  A   4
808426  2020-09-28  A   2
848057  2020-09-23  A   1
865751  2020-09-21  A   2
886630  2020-09-18  A   3
901095  2020-09-16  A   47
938648  2020-09-10  A   2
969909  2020-09-07  A   3
1021548 2020-08-31  A   2
1032254 2020-08-30  A   8
1077443 2020-08-25  A   5
1089670 2020-08-24  A   24
1098843 2020-08-23  A   16
1102025 2020-08-22  A   23
1179347 2020-08-12  A   1
1305700 2020-07-29  A   1
1316343 2020-07-28  A   1
1399930 2020-07-19  A   1
1451864 2020-07-15  A   1
1463195 2020-07-14  A   15
2129080 2020-05-19  A   1
2143468 2020-05-18  A   1
```

Current Output:

```
         date      sku  qty
556603  2020-10-25  A   6
590904  2020-10-21  A   5
595307  2020-10-20  A   31
602678  2020-10-19  A   11
615022  2020-10-18  A   2
641077  2020-10-16  A   1
650203  2020-10-15  A   3
655363  2020-10-14  A   NaN
667919  2020-10-13  A   NaN
674990  2020-10-12  A   NaN
703901  2020-10-09  A   NaN
715411  2020-10-08  A   NaN
721557  2020-10-07  A   NaN
740515  2020-10-06  A   NaN
752670  2020-10-05  A   NaN
808426  2020-09-28  A   2
848057  2020-09-23  A   1
865751  2020-09-21  A   2
886630  2020-09-18  A   3
901095  2020-09-16  A   47
938648  2020-09-10  A   NaN
969909  2020-09-07  A   NaN
1021548 2020-08-31  A   NaN
1032254 2020-08-30  A   NaN
1077443 2020-08-25  A   NaN
1089670 2020-08-24  A   NaN
1098843 2020-08-23  A   NaN
1102025 2020-08-22  A   NaN
1179347 2020-08-12  A   NaN
1305700 2020-07-29  A   NaN
1316343 2020-07-28  A   1
1399930 2020-07-19  A   1
1451864 2020-07-15  A   1
1463195 2020-07-14  A   15
2129080 2020-05-19  A   1
2143468 2020-05-18  A   1
```

I have had a look around but can't seem to find what is causing this error.

Comment: must be going blind but i can't see any commas in your input dataframe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your issue:

```
# toy df
df

  qty
0   1
1  2,
2   3

df['qty'].str.replace(',', '')

0    NaN
1      2
2    NaN
Name: qty, dtype: object
```

I created `df` by doing this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'qty': [1, '2,', 3]})
```

In other words, your column has mixed data types - some values are integers while others are strings. So when you apply `.str` methods on mixed types, non str types are converted to NaN to indicate "hey it doesn't make sense to run a str method on an int".

---

You may fix this by converting the entire column to string, then back to int:

```
df['qty'].astype(str).str.replace(',', '').astype(int)
```

Or if you want something a litte more robust, try

```
df['qty'] = pd.to_numeric(
    df['qty'].astype(str).str.extract('(\d+)', expand=False), errors='coerce')
```